# I can not request with postman

Tags: api, postman

I want to test my API with `postman` but when I make a request this error appears:

> Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 0.0.0.0:8080

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: my API runs and give me this address http://0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a non-address. I'm inferring that you want to access your `localhost` so try `localhost:8080`

`0.0.0.0` is generally referring to 'all IPs', so it might be listed as the *incoming* IP for what you're trying to access, if that makes sense?

edit
Looking at your comment, trying doing the request against your machine private IP (e.g. `192.168.10.5:8080`)

Comment: now give me this mistake: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED